# Spring LDAP Authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, openldap

I have made a `Spring MVC` user login Java application, but I want the user login to get `authenticated` using `OpenLDAP` ?

Can someone explain the procedure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-custom-login-form-annotation-example/) would be helpful for you.

Comment: This doesn't use LDAP authentication, I want to use that too.